# To limit concurrency OR NOT to limit concurrency? (within a single ASP.NET request)

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, concurrency, .net-core, scalability

There are plenty of answers on HOW to limit concurrency of async I/O operations and/or their continuations -- using a custom scheduler, SemaphorSlim etc. My question is: **does it make sense to do that** in a standard ASP.NET MVC / WebAPI scenario?

We have a typical enterprise API that serves as backend for a customer-facing SPA. Many API requests involve calling dozens of downstream web services, which we by now have mostly converted to async I/O with TAP (async/await). Many of these remote service calls are started in parallel, without awaiting, and then awaited in bulk using `Task.WhenAll`. Sometimes WhenAll is done over a fixed number of tasks, and sometimes we start a remote call *per item in collection* - which leads to spawning an unknown (but usually low, under a dozen) number of tasks and then awaiting them with WhenAll.

[As I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463661/task-continuation-parallel-execution-with-async-await), this causes continuations of these tasks (i.e. the logic that deserializes their responses) to get scheduled on the ThreadPool. Which leads to my question: would running these CPU-bound continuations in parallel not lead to excessive pressure on the ThreadPool? Should we develop some sort of middleware that would limit concurrency of the continuations of the async I/O tasks started inside a single request by scheduling them to a custom scheduler?

Would that allow for better scalability of our app, by reducing the number of ThreadPool threads allocated by any given request, which would allow for more concurrent requests to be served before we'd start running out of ThreadPool threads (or getting throttled by the ThreadPool growth)?

Or is this rather useless, and we should simply trust the default ThreadScheduler+ThreadPool's ability to schedule all tasks to the available CPU cores across whatever number of concurrent requests?

### FYI to everyone attempting to answer:

This is a rather mature system at a very large company, well-scrutinized by dozens of experts (including myself), in production for one US state, about to enter production at the national level. Suggestions like "measure first", "know whether you are IO vs. CPU bound", "try AppInsights" and "don't try to be smarter than Microsoft" are the very first things we ourselves have obviously thought about. The level of guidance we're seeking is more like: **has anyone here implemented an all-async ASP.NET Web API system at the US national level and has real-life experience with async/WhenAll concurrency?**

Comment: It's difficult to answer in a generic way. The best is to have a maximum IO-bound (or non CPU-bound) operations running async and a minimum CPU context (thread) switches, so you maximize all processors (non only CPU) usage. You should first *measure* what you already have before trying to get "too smart". Plus, the absolute performance doesn't exist. If you reach your goal with the default (decent) mechanism, why take any risk, IMHO?

Comment: Doesn't this call for using something like a GraphQL server for you?

Comment: @tarunlalwani I don't see a connection TBH. We are just making lots of downstream web service calls, many in parallel. Is that something GraphQL could help with?

Comment: Yes, it can help with you that. Simplifying your .NET code, you should definitely explore it. Also with your current setup you should write all your use case down and find which calls your want to prioritise. Also when you said you fetch item in a loop, you should always limit the # of parallel calls that happen. Else one heavy record can degrade performance of other calls on the server. There is no # based answer on this, you will need to put down the limits, stress the system and fine tune it. But for sure don't run everything parallel without a limit

Comment: I think code to limit concurrency would introduce more performance overhead on CPU to achieve any benefits. .NET already has good mechanism in place. But replacing it with custom one will be time consuming and testing it would be another nightmare. Instead you can introduce some middleware with some sort of caching to reduce number of calls to remote or db servers. Caching is far efficient then limiting concurrency. Try Microsoft Application Insights to watch dependency calls, it will tell you which calls you can cache to improve.

Comment: Thanks all, we are a large company that already thought about all these basic things. I added more details to the question in case someone has some experience they can share.

Comment: If you think people that "attempt to answer" here have not worked on real life scenarios with very large companies, why do you ask for the community free help? Your question is very vague w/o any metrics/experiments/benchmarks/code/real stuff. What else do you expect but vague answers w/o any metrics? Devil is always in the details

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. All details relevant to the situation are there in the question. There are no details further than this, I expect this to be answerable based on experience with large-scale API implementation in ASP.NET invoking downstream services in parallel using async/await plus solid understanding of the ThreadPool differences between .NET 4 and dotnetcore, plus decent understanding of async custom task schedulers.

Answer (score 6):

@tarun-lalwani make some great points in the comments

But I'll mention the solid advice to never preoptimize.  A mid-range desktop today can easily handle a threadpool of 16 (which can handle hundreds of waiting tasks generally), a good server can handle a much larger thread pool than that, how much does your time cost vs the cost of a replacement or new server, probably less than 6 months, very possibly less than 3 months.

Any performance problem comes down to the bottlenecks, the system can only perform as fast as the slowest bottleneck.  So improving those specific bottlenecks, in the real-world system, is how to improve performance.  How to scale those groups of bottlenecks is how to improve scalability.  There are still a lot of differences between desktop and server hardware, so I'll stress again that you need to see real-world not in-vitro metrics on these things before putting in weeks/months of effort into fixing a "problem" that may not be there.

GraphQL as mentioned allows you to rearrange where the bottlenecks occur, allowing you to distribute them more evenly, to better utilize the hardware you already have.  Which is also true of many of the more modern design patterns.

In summary, it only makes sense to limit a process that if and when it becomes a problem.

Comment: Thanks, we are a large company that already thought about all these basic things. That said, thanks for attempting to answer. "The only bird gets the worm" :)

Comment: Thanks. Just saw your update now. I really think you just have to use JMeter or similar to simulate the amount of traffic you're expecting, and monitor the CPU Queue in perfmon, and see what happens. It also very much depends on what sort of SLA you want, do you want to ensure 99% of requests which have reasonable number of Tasks return quicker than the 1% that has a huge number of Tasks, or treat them all the same and when that 1% happens it might slow the others. If the former is desired I'd try writing your limiting middleware and test to make sure it doesn't make anything else worse